# Windows phone 8 slider binding works only after a click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, slider, mediaelement

I am writing an audio app on Windows Phone 8. I've created a MediaElement and a seek-bar(slider):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" CurrentStateChanged="GetTrackDuration" />
<Slider x:Name="playerSeekBar" Value="{Binding ElementName=player, Path=Position, 
 Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1"/>
```

And this is my converter code:

```
public class PositionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double position = 0;
        TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.Parse(value.ToString());
        position = timespan.TotalSeconds;

        return position;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value);
    }
}
```

And here is the CurrentStateChanged event code:

```
private void GetTrackDuration(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var player = (MediaElement)sender;
    if (player.CurrentState == System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing)
        playerSeekBar.Maximum = player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
}
```

It all seems to work OK, however there is one problem with the binding to slider - it doesn't update until I click somewhere inside the app - I mean i may click on a button that isn't connected with slider or media element or on a empty space. After I click the slider is being updated and everything works nice. BTW, the music plays normally - even at the beginning when the slider is not being updated. I tried to look on the Internet, however I am not sure what to ask, that's why I am asking You for help. If someone just knows where I could search for the solution, I would be very grateful!:)

Thank You for Your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem when Slider gets Focus, I've tried to find a solution with redirecting Focus, but so far - I haven't found it. Instead I've a diffrent proposal and few remarks to your code:

1. Get track duration when Media is Opened not when PlayState changes:

   ```
   private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       playerSeekBar.Maximum = (sender as MediaElement).NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
   }
   ```
2. Your Slider will probably be updated every little change of MediaElement's position. I think it isn't needed - it can be updated for example every second. So my proposal is - bind your Slider to a property, and notify PropertyChanged every second (use `DispatcherTimer`):

   ```
   // In this case we need INotifyPropertyChanged - 
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {

   // implementing interface
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void RaiseProperty(string property = null)
   {
       if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
           this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
   }

   // Property for Binding
   public double SlideValue
   {
       get { return player.Position.TotalSeconds; }
       set { player.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value); }
   }

   DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(); // timer

   // Get the duration when Media File is opened
   private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       playerSeekBar.Maximum = (sender as MediaElement).NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
   }

   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;  // Set the DataContext
       Play.Click += Play_Click;  // My play method
       timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
       timer.Tick += (s, e) => { RaiseProperty("SlideValue"); };
   }

   private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       player.AutoPlay = true;
       player.Source = new Uri("music.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
       timer.Start();  // DON'T forget to start the timer.
   }
   ```

In this case you no longer need Converters, and your XAML code can look like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" MediaOpened="player_MediaOpened"/>
<Slider x:Name="playerSeekBar" Value="{Binding SlideValue, Mode=TwoWay}" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1"/>
```

Above code probably still needs some improvements, but works quite fine.

**EDIT** - method without DataBinding and INotifyPropertyChanged

You can also accomplish your task simpler way without Binding, just using `Timer` and `LostMouseCapture`:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private double totalSeconds = 1;

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        totalSeconds = (sender as MediaElement).NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Play.Click += Play_Click;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => { playerSeekBar.Value += (double)(1 / totalSeconds); };
        playerSeekBar.LostMouseCapture += (s, e) =>
        { player.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(playerSeekBar.Value * totalSeconds); };
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.AutoPlay = true;
        player.Source = new Uri("music.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        timer.Start();  // DON'T forget to start the timer.
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" MediaOpened="player_MediaOpened"/>
<Slider x:Name="playerSeekBar" Value="0" SmallChange="0.01" Maximum="1.0"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer! I tried to use what You've said, however a small problem appeared - when I change events from CurrentStateChanged to MediaOpen, then my slider moves too fast and comes to the end too soon. At the moment I don't know why it acts like that. Still thanks for the help!:)

Comment: @RomanPylypets That is weird, as I have checked it should work. Please check in debug mode what value is passed to Slider.Maximum.

Comment: @RomanPylypets I've added an other way of managing the slider - if you don't need binding.

Comment: thank You very much for Your help - Your code works nice, it was my mistake - I was assigning player.Source twice with different uris.

Comment: @RomanPylypets You are welcome. Thanks for the information. Best wishes and happy coding.