# Thumb.DragStarted event not working in visual studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a small music player for windows phone. I have added a slider functionality in the player. The slider works fine as the music plays. But I want to change the media according to how much i drag the slider, but cannot find any relevant event for it. I have tried value changed but it does not help. Also I tried Thumb.Dragstarted event but my visual studio gives an error.. this is the code so far:

XAML:

```
<Slider AllowDrop="True" x:Name="sld1"  Thumb.DragStarted="sld1_DragStarted" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="58,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351" ValueChanged="sld1_ValueChanged"/>
<MediaElement x:Name="bleep" Source="abcd.wav" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed" MediaEnded="bleep_MediaEnded"/>
```

C#:

```
public Page1()
    {
     DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
     timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
     timer.Start();
    }
private bool userIsDraggingSlider = false;
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bleep.Source != null) && (bleep.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan) && (!userIsDraggingSlider))
        {
            sld1.Minimum = 0;
            sld1.Maximum = bleep.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            sld1.Value = bleep.Position.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

    private void sld1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        tm_passed.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sld1.Value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
private void sld1_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
            {
                    userIsDraggingSlider = true;
            }

private void sld1_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                    userIsDraggingSlider = false;
                    bleep.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sld1.Value);
            }
```

But since the DragCompleted and DragStarted events are not working I cannot provide the drag functionality to the slider.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It says: " The local property 'dragstarted' can only be applied to types that are derived from 'Thumb' " @Kulasangar

Answer (score 0):

What I identified from the `Thumb` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is that, you can't simply add `Thumb.DragStarted="sld1_DragStarted` within your `Slider`. You'll be able to add that kind of `event` only for `Thumb` control. Refer the bottom of the article for sample code.

Comment: okk. got it. But then how should i provide the functionality i want to the slider, so that i can change the media position according to how much i drag the slider? @Kulasangar

Comment: You could try the `Converter` class: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/08/28/control-position-of-the-song-using-slider-bar-in-windows-phone-using-converter-class.aspx & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115537/windows-phone-8-slider-binding-works-only-after-a-click